# Postgresql - ROLLBACK appearing immediately on function call

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Postgres 10.6 - AWS RDS x.large w/30gb Ram

We're seeing a decline in performance over the last few weeks which we're tentatively putting down to the introduction of two new BI tools, however as part of a general clean-up exercise I've been taking a look at some of our stored functions and the way they're structured.

Take the procedure below;

```
create function my_func() returns void
language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN

insert into table_b
select col_1, col2
from table_a
on conflict do nothing etc etc

    insert into table_c
select col_1, col2
from table_b
on conflict do nothing etc etc

END
$$;
```

I've noticed that whenever a function is kicked-off from cron (whether I've adapted it or not), I query `pg_stat_activity` and find TWO entries for each run, the function itself and then a ROLLBACK with the same age, as below;

```
SELECT age(clock_timestamp(),query_start), query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%'
ORDER BY query_start desc
;
```

```
0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 42 mins 28.099616 secs. --  my_func()
0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 42 mins 28.160319 ROLLBACK
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean BEGIN/COMMIT? The BEGIN/END in the description above is used to create a block of code, not a transaction.

Comment: @MatsKindahl thanks yes I did mean COMMIT and I've removed that part of the question as it's confusing and not relevant.

Comment: PostgreSQL itself wouldn't start a second connection, so it must be some software on the client side.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it’s being kicked off from cron using psql-c. If I run it locally then I don’t observe the same duplicate connection.

Comment: @Rob A possible hypothesis is that the rollback is because a commit is missing. If a connection is just closed without committing the transaction, it will result in a rollback. Have you checked that?

Comment: @MatsKindahl It will cause a rollback, but not a second connection. Also, `cron` won't do that. The problem remains mysterious.